# How to make Django ModelForm filed to update the attrs, so the style can be displayed successfully

Tags: python, django

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Project

class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'featured_image', 'description', 'demo_link', 'source_link', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }


    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__int__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
        for name, field in self.fields.item():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

I am trying to display my dynamic form with the correct styling. but this method doesn't seem to work. How can I fix it?

```
    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__int__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
        for name, field in self.fields.item():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})`
```

This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **init** magic method, you're using "item" instead of "items".
Change the line for name, field in
self.fields.item(): to for name, field in self.fields.items():

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

Also fix `__int__` to `__init__`

I hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  It still didn't change anything on the style of the form. I also tried to test out the line     def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'}), but the widget.attrs.update line seems not working. What else I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try to change the class name to something else instead of "input"?  Just to make sure. Also, did you try to check via inspect elements if the class is showing there or not?

Comment: @Xinyu Yang have you really took @dostogircse171 code? because you always write `int` instead of `init`! Not only in the method name, but also in the super call to init.

Comment: I tried to change class name and it didn't work. Then I inspected the element, the class name I tried to assign by using widget.attrs.update did not appear in the inspect. I think the widget.attrs.update did not work, which I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried the same code I have given on my answer? Because on your old code you had __int__ instead of __init__ 
I just tried replicating the code on my local server and its working fine for me.

Comment: @XinyuYang - Awesome. Happy to help. Please accept the answer and give it a upvote :)